# Given a byte in 2’s complement What is 0x56 in decimal?

Tags: computer-science

a) -13
b) -110
c) 38
d) none of the above

Im not sure on how to do this question. What I have done so far is convert the hexadecimal number into a decimal, but since it's already in 2's complement, how do I know the sign?

Comment: There's a computer science stack exchange. Your question might suit that site better.

Comment: $42 {}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Do you understand how the twos-complement representation works?

Answer (score 1):

Since the leading bit is $0$ the number is positive.  You don't have to worry about the $2$s complement, just convert it to decimal.  $5\cdot 16+6=86$